# Mocking open() on pathlib.Path to return a mock file handle with unittest.mock

Tags: python, python-unittest.mock

Say I have a method that gets passed some paths, reads the files at each of these paths, then returns a dictionary from file name to file content, like so:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack
from pathlib import Path


class ClassToTest:
    def method_to_test(self, *paths: Path):
        with ExitStack() as stack:
            files = [stack.enter_context(path.open(mode='r')) for path in paths]
            return {f.name: f.read() for f in files}
```

Now say I want to test that if I pass in e.g. `C:\wherever\file_name.xyz` that the returned dictionary contains the key `file_name.xyz`. Since my method under test is opening and reading files, I want to mock out the Path object. I think I can do *something like*:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, mock_open

class Tests:
    def test(self):
        mock_path = Mock(spec=Path)
        mock_path.open = mock_open()
        # ???

        files = ClassToTest().method_to_test(mock_path)
        assert 'file_name.xyz' in files
```

But I can't figure out how to get `f.name` (i.e. `mock_path.open().name`) to return `file_name.xyz`.

Comment: Depending on how heavily you rely on the file system, you could use [pyfakefs](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs) to mock out the complete filesystem (yes, I'm a contributor to that...) - that would allow you to create fake files and test both the file names and contents of the files.

Answer (score 3):

Try `assert mock_path.open().name in files`. Should just work as you are using the mocking library. It'll be a fragile test though as `mock_path.name != mock_path.open().name`

If you're using pytest, then just use the [`tmp_path`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html) fixture which is unique for each test invocation.

```
import pytest

def f(path):
    with path.open() as f:
        return {f.name: f.read()}

def test_f(tmp_path):
    name = 'some_file.txt'
    content = 'hello\nworld'
    path = tmp_path / name
    path.write_text(content)

    result = f(path)

    assert str(path) in result
    assert content in result.values()

def test_g(tmp_path):
    assert list(tmp_path.iterdir()) == []
```

Comment: say for the sake of argument that I wanted `mock_path.open().name` to actually return `'file_name.xyz'`?

Comment: Just assign to it. `mock_open` creates a callable mock. Mocks always return the same objects for each attribute unless you use the `side_effect` parameter. So you can just do `mock_path.open().name = 'xyz'`, and then future calls to `mock_path.open().name` will return `'xyz'`.